# How to change icon colour, text colour and add shadow of H3 tag onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, header

New to this JavaScript stuff but i am trying lol. I have a toggle the colour of the text currently changes colour (Red) when i click on one, then changes back to black when i click on another, then the now selected toggles font is red. my question is, is there a way to change the background to white, still have the text change to red and to also add a drop shadow,then change back to the original settings once another google has been selected, and so fourth. Will this be compatible on most browsers?

I have tried altering my already working script but no luck.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.header h3').on('click', function() {
        $('.header h3').css('color', 'black');
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    });
});
```

```css
a#order::before {
    content:'';
    padding:0;
    background: url("./Images/bell1.png") no-repeat !important;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    /*    margin-top: 5%;*/
    margin-top: 8px;
    /*padding-left: 15px;*/
}

/*restaurant icons*/
a#restt::before {
    content:'';
    padding:0;
    background: url("./Images/knife_folk1.png") no-repeat !important;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    /*    margin-top: 5%;*/
    margin-top: 8px;
    font: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
    color: #8fb653;
    font-weight: 400;

    /*padding-left: 15px;*/
}

/*account icon*/
a#francc::before {
    content:'';
    padding:0;
    background: url("./Images/icon.png") no-repeat !important;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    /*    margin-top: 5%;*/
    margin-top: 8px;
    /*padding-left: 15px;*/
}
```

```html
<a  id="order" class="header" href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Order');"><h3 id="orderr">Orders</h3></a>

<a id="restt" class ="header"href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Rest');"><h3>Your Restaurants</h3></a>

<a id="francc"  class ="header" href="#" onclick="toggleVisibility('Franc');"><h3>Your Account</h3></a>
```

Each has a icon which is not showing, but can be seen on the image before:

[image]

Comment: generally easier to add and remove classes...then put all the styles into css stylesheet rules

Comment: FYI: java != javascript

Comment: Check out toggleClass() and use that to toggle on and off your class for your event.

Comment: Have you considered enclosing your `h3` inside a div? That way you can control the background color and add some shadow into it when it is focused and get it back to normal when it is unfocused. You can do this by setting its `onfocus` and `onblur` events of your div. And by the way, don't forget to set the `tabindex` attribute of those divs to `-1` so that the focus and blur events of the div will work

Comment: Thank you all i will try

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.header h3').on('click', function() {
        $('a h3').css('color', 'black');
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    });
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/js55kr4c/

you can also add to your css this:

```
a h3{
    color:black;
}
```

(so that all h3's are displayed in black color on load)

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/js55kr4c/1/

hope it helps you and others, T.

Comment: Hi. what i wanted to do was to have the font colour, bg colour and icon colour change. Ive been playing around and can now get either the bg colour or the font colour to change but not both at the same time

Comment: @jerneva: I have updated the fiddle. Have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/js55kr4c/2/ Also, if you think that my answer has helped you, please accept it and upvote. Thanks

Comment: i have tried this and also modified this. It doesn't work 100% is does what my coding does, which is a white box behind the text, and deactivated the text selector font.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to achieve. Font color and icon color do change as well as the background color (as you asked in your first comment)... What else would you like to add or modify?

Comment: no the example works perfectly, just not in my text editor for some odd reason.